# Azure Function - Call Google API from within Azure Function (C#)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am attempting to create an Azure Function using .NET Core to call to the YouTube API to retrieve some metrics on my videos.

Before calling the API I need to Authenticate with Google in a server to server method since this function will run daily with NO user interaction.

I've followed a number of examples (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) and I'm having no luck getting properly authenticated when running from Azure.

Is this possible? And can anyone point me to an example of this working?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You have a timer trigger azure function that will run daily. And you want to use Youtube API to fetch some data on its invocation?

Comment: Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Answer (score 1):

For server-to-server interactions you need a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account), which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end-user. **Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required**.

```
public class Program
{
    // A known public activity.
    private static String ACTIVITY_ID = "z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plus API - Service Account");
        Console.WriteLine("==========================");

        String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Plus API Sample",
        });

        Activity activity = service.Activities.Get(ACTIVITY_ID).Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("  Activity: " + activity.Object.Content);
        Console.WriteLine("  Video: " + activity.Object.Attachments[0].Url);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The above sample code creates a `ServiceAccountCredential`. The required scopes are set and there is a call to `FromCertificate`, which loads the private key from the given `X509Certificate2`. As in all other samples code, the credential is set as `HttpClientInitializer`.

For more details about service account flow you could refer to this [article](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account).

Comment: You can also use the desktop flow. It just requires a one time consent which can be done in the oauth2 playground. Service to service account does not seem to be recommended by Google.